# split a string in a column and pivot in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014

I am using sql server 2014 and I have a table like this (##tt_allresults)

```
ID      |       Area        |       Event                                                                           |
1       |       FB1         |   Dev_Chg, Old Value: 0, New Value: 50, Workstation: Blah1, Function: Blah1 func      |
1       |       FB2         |   Dev_Chg, Old Value: 99, New Value: 5, Workstation: Blah2, Function: Blah2 func      |       
1       |       FB1         |   Dev_Chg, Old Value: 50, New Value: 55, Workstation: Blah1, Function: Blah1 func     |
```

I would like to from a table like so (Expected Output)

```
Area    |   Old Value   |       New Value   |       Function        |
FB1     |   0           |       50          |   Blah1 func          |   
FB2     |   99          |       5           |   Blah2 func          |   
FB1     |   50          |       55          |   Blah1 func          |
```

This is what i have tried so far

```
Declare @id int
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ##tt_allresults)
BEGIN
Select Top 1 @id = Id from ##tt_allresults

-- Do the work --
Declare @area nvarchar(100)
set @area = (Select Area from ##tt_allresults where id = @id)

Insert into ##tt_changedetails
select @area, * from fnsplit((Select [event] from ##tt_allresults where id = @id),',')

-- Scrap the ID and Move On --
Delete ##tt_allresults where ID = @id
END


select * from ##tt_changedetails
```

I get the following result

```
Area    |       ChangeDetails       |
FB1     |   Dev_Chg                 |
FB1     |   Old value :0            |
FB1     |   New Value :50           |
FB1     |   Workstation :blah1      |
FB1     |   Function :blah1 func    |
FB2     |   Dev_Chg                 |
FB2     |   Old value :99           |
FB2     |   New Value :5            |
FB2     |   Workstation :blah2      |
FB2     |   Function :blah2 func    |
FB1     |   Dev_Chg                 |
FB1     |   Old value :50           |
FB1     |   New Value :55           |
FB1     |   Workstation :blah1      |
FB1     |   Function :blah1 func    |
```

How do i split my initial table and pivot it based on the split. I want to see the following result

```
FB1     |   0           |       50          |   Blah1 func          |   
FB2     |   99          |       5           |   Blah2 func          |   
FB1     |   50          |       55          |   Blah1 func          |
```

Comment: @Chanukya - I have updated the question.  If you have any further question please feel free to ask.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: @iamdave - The expected output table in my question.

Comment: @iamdave - Anymore questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: First, get the result you got, then do another split based on the ":"; then do three pivots separately for Old Value, New Value, Workstation, and JOIN them together (or you can use a CASE for this second part). There has been plenty of answers for this.

Comment: @Abe check my answer . I tested it on my local server it shows desired output . I just used a function to split the event data in to table and then used it have a look  . If this is what you want please mark and like my answer

Comment: @Abe still one catch . When we pivot on area the values get combined so the output of my query return 2 records not one so you need to work a little on the query .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a UDF, can all be done with the help of a CROSS APPLY and an a little XML

You can expand or contract as needed.  I left 9 Positions to illustrate

**1) Without a Function**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Area varchar(25),Event varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'FB1','Dev_Chg, Old Value: 0, New Value: 50, Workstation: Blah1, Function: Blah1 func'),
(1,'FB2','Dev_Chg, Old Value: 99, New Value: 5, Workstation: Blah2, Function: Blah2 func'),
(1,'FB1','Dev_Chg, Old Value: 50, New Value: 55, Workstation: Blah1, Function: Blah1 func')

Select A.Area
      ,[Old Value] = Substring(Pos2,CharIndex(':',Pos2)+1,Len(Pos2))
      ,[New Value] = Substring(Pos3,CharIndex(':',Pos3)+1,Len(Pos3))
      ,[Function]  = Substring(Pos5,CharIndex(':',Pos5)+1,Len(Pos5))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                 From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select A.Event as [*] For XML Path('')),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
       ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Area    Old Value   New Value   Function
FB1     0           50          Blah1 func
FB2     99          5           Blah2 func
FB1     50          55          Blah1 func
```

**Or 2 With A Function**

```
Select A.Area
      ,[Old Value] = Substring(Pos2,CharIndex(':',Pos2)+1,Len(Pos2))
      ,[New Value] = Substring(Pos3,CharIndex(':',Pos3)+1,Len(Pos3))
      ,[Function]  = Substring(Pos5,CharIndex(':',Pos5)+1,Len(Pos5))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row](A.Event,',') B
```

---

**The UDF if needed**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
            ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
     From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select @String as [*] For XML Path('')),@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
)
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('John <test> Cappelletti',' ')
```

---

If it helps with the visualization, the CROSS APPLY (which can easily be a TVF) produces the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct query I hope it helps  .

```
          declare @str varchar(1000) 

        declare @temp as table (id int , area varchar(10) , [event] varchar(100))

        insert into @temp (id,area,[event]) values (1,'FB1','Dev_Chg, Old Value: 0, New Value: 50, Workstation: Blah1, Function: Blah1 func')
        insert into @temp (id,area,[event]) values (1,'FB2','Dev_Chg, Old Value: 99, New Value: 5, Workstation: Blah2, Function: Blah2 func')
        insert into @temp (id,area,[event]) values (1,'FB1','Dev_Chg, Old Value: 50, New Value: 55, Workstation: Blah1, Function: Blah1 func')

        set @str ='Dev_Chg, Old Value: 0, New Value: 50, Workstation: Blah1, Function: Blah1 func'



        select  * from (
        select area,  RTRIM( LTRIM(  SUBSTRING( String,0 , CHARINDEX (':',String ))) )as theader  , SUBSTRING( String,  CHARINDEX (':',String )+1,15) as tvalue from (
        select * from 
        @temp cross apply 
        dbo.ufn_CSVToTable ([event])
        ) b
        where b.String!='Dev_Chg'

        ) 
         as final 
         pivot (  max ( tvalue ) for theader in ([Old Value] , [New Value],[Workstation],[Function])
         ) as pvt
```

-- I used a tabled valued function  to complete it the source is this

```
        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CSVToTable] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(8000) )
        RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] nVARCHAR(1000) )
        AS
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @String    nVARCHAR(1000)

            WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                        LEN(@StringInput)))
                SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                             ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 0),
                                             LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

                INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
                VALUES ( @String )
            END

            RETURN
        END
```

Comment: What is 'String' in your answer?

Comment: @Abe this is the ouput of the user defined function which I CROSS Apply . Although as I mentioned that with current data you  presented we have a issue that you cannot pivot correctly it show 2 records instead of 3 . You need to rework a little but almost all of your question is answered in the query . I hope this is helpful answer for you .

Comment: I have executed your function and I am unable to run your script. 'String' is the issue.  Am I missing something.

Comment: strange because it run well . and as you can see the function the output of the table as a column with name String . So it should not be the issue.